# JAVA FXML checkbox and textfield bonding

Tags: java, javafx-8

Hello im building a java project using NetBeans IDE and SceneBuilder for the FXML files.
my question is how to make a textfield disabled , when a checkbox is checked , using sceneBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

In FXML you would do

```xml
<CheckBox fx:id="myCheckBox" />
<TextField fx:id="myTextField" disable="${myCheckBox.selected}"/>
```

though of course is is much more natural to do this in the controller with

```
myTextField.disableProperty().bind(myCheckBox.selectedProperty());
```